# How to change the text inside of p tag with a class by using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I want to change the text inside a `p` tag which has a class `info` by using innerHTML, but it does not work properly. Is there somthing wrong in this code? Thanks.

Javascript;

```
var pokeDescription = document.getElementsByClassName("info");
for(var n=0; n < pokeDescription; n++){
    pokeDescription[n].innerHTML = data.info.description;
}
```

HTML;

```
<p class="info">Description here</p>
```

Comment: n < pokeDescription.length

Comment: Could you share your html?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `.length`

```
   var pokeDescription = document.getElementsByClassName("info");
    for(var n=0; n < pokeDescription.length; n++){
        pokeDescription[n].innerHTML = data.info.description;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `length` field in your loop:

```
    var pokeDescription = document.getElementsByClassName("info");
    for(var n=0; n < pokeDescription.length; n++){
        pokeDescription[n].innerHTML = data.info.description;
    }
```